# Explanation of rlang operators used to write functions

Tags: r, rlang

I recently posted two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66753999/how-to-use-tabyl-with-two-variables-within-a-function), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767080/iterate-over-specified-columns-for-crosstabs-in-r)) related to functions I was trying to write. I received useful answers to each, which resulted in the following two functions:

```
second_table <- function(dat, variable1, variable2){
 dat %>% 
  tabyl({{variable1}}, {{variable2}}, show_na = FALSE) %>% 
  adorn_percentages("row") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 1) %>% 
   adorn_ns() 

 }
```

And

```
second_table2 = function(dat, variable1, variable2){
  variable1 <- sym(variable1)
  
  dat %>% 
    tabyl(!!variable1, {{variable2}}, show_na = FALSE) %>% 
    adorn_percentages("row") %>% 
    adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 1) %>% 
    adorn_ns() 
  
}
```

These functions work as intended, but I had never used the rlang package before and am still confused about the difference between the {{}} operator and !! + sym() after looking through the available documentation and writing some additional functions. I don't like to use code that I don't fully understand and am sure I will have further use for these rlang operators in the future, so would greatly appreciate a plain-language explanation of what the difference is between these operators.

Comment: There seem to be plenty of existing guides like: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/ and https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html and https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html. Can you make your question more specific? It doesn't seem useful just to copy the existing explanations here.

Comment: `{{` replaces `!!` and is simpler, see above links

Comment: Thanks. I had gotten the gist from guides such as those linked above, but am still confused about specific use cases where each makes more sense such as in the example in my initial question. I'm most interested in determining why you would want to use both {{}} and !! with sym() together in one function if {{}} is designed to replace !!.

Comment: Sometimes you need direct access to the `sym`, object, other times you don't. In this example, there's no reason to use `sym()` and `!!` because you are using the variable directly. But what if you wanted to change or alter the variable some how. Then you would need to manipulate the `sym` first. Other the other common reason to use `sym() + !!` is to also get the name of the variable as a string with `as_label()`. You can't do what using `{{}}`

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R has a particular feature called non-standard evaluation (NSE), where expressions are used as-is instead of being evaluated. Most people first encounter NSE when they load packages:

```
a <- "rlang"

print(a)         # Standard evaluation - the expression a is evaluated to its value
# [1] "rlang"

library(a)       # Non-standard evaluation - the expression a is used as-is
# Error in library(a) : there is no package called ‘a’
```

`rlang` enables sophisticated NSE by providing three main functions to capture unevaluated symbols and expressions:

- `sym("x")` captures a symbol (i.e., variable name, column name, etc.). Older versions allowed for `sym(x)`, but I think the latest version of `rlang` forces the input to be a string.
- `expr(a + b)` captures arbitrary expressions
- `quo(a + b)` captures arbitrary expressions AND the environment where these expression were defined.

The difference between `expr`essions and `quo`sures is that evaluating the former will be done in the immediate environment, while the latter is always evaluated in the environment where the expression was captured:

```
f <- function(e) {a <- 2; b <- 3; eval_tidy(e)}
a <- 5; b <- 10

f(expr(a+b))   # Evaluated inside f
# [1] 5

f(quo(a+b))    # Evaluated in the environment where it is captured
# [1] 15
```

All three verbs have `en`-equivalents: `ensym`, `enexpr` and `enquo`. These are used to capture symbols and expressions provided to a function from within that function. This is useful when you want to remove the need for a user of the function to use `sym`, etc. themselves:

```
f <- function(x) {enexpr(x)}      # Expression captured within a function
f(a+b)

# This has exact equivalence to

f <- function(x) {x}
f(expr(a+b))                      # The user has to do the capture themselves
```

In all cases, the operator `!!` evaluates symbols and expressions. Think of it as `eval()` on steroids, because `!!` forces immediate evaluation that takes precedence over everything else. Among other things, this can be useful for iterative construction of more complicated expressions:

```
a <- expr(b + 2)
expr(d * !!a)      # a is evaluated immediately
# d * (b + 2)

expr(d * eval(a))  # evaluation of a is delayed
# d * eval(a)
```

With all that said, `{{x}}` is shorthand notation for `!!enquo(x)`

Comment: So could I use this to capture the symbol on the LHS of the `<-` operator.  That is, for example, could I get "x" from `x <- 5` and "y" from `y <- 10`?

Comment: That is best done with ASTs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60083614/300187